# cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: java, android

```
chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

    Message(topic_id);

    listView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
    listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);



    buttonSend = findViewById(R.id.send);
    fileSend = findViewById(R.id.file_send);
    chatText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mychat);





    //  delete_btn = findViewById(R.id.);


    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        // View select;
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, final int position, long id) {


                    if ( view != null){

                  view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB2DFDB);

                 }



            String value = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            msgid = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageID();
            message = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageText();
            userid1 = chatMessages.get(position).getUserId();
            username = chatMessages.get(position).getMessageUser();
            replyuser = chatMessages.get(position).getReply_user();





            if (sno.equals(userid1)) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB2DFDB);
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello"+userid1+msgid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               // ImageView edit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.delete_icon);
             //   edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             //   );
                topic.setText(getString(R.string.edit));
                myToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.edit);


              //  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                topic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        chatMessages.remove(position);
                        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                        userid1 = null;
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        chatText.setText(message);


                    }
                });
                myToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        chatMessages.remove(position);
                        userid1 = null;
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        chatText.setText(message);



                    }
                });

            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xFFB2DFDB);
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hello"+userid1+msgid,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                topic.setText(getString(R.string.reply));
                myToolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.replay);
                // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
             //   reply = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.reply_icon);
             //   reply.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                topic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        replylayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.reply_layout);
                        replylayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        TextView replay_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reply_user);
                        TextView replay_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reply_text);
                        ImageButton cancell = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cancell_btn);

                        replay_name.setText(username);
                        replay_text.setText(message);


                        cancell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                replylayout.removeAllViews();
                                startActivity(getIntent());

                            }
                        });


                    }
                });
           myToolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                replylayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.reply_layout);
                replylayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                TextView replay_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reply_user);
                TextView replay_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.reply_text);
                ImageButton cancell = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cancell_btn);

                replay_name.setText(username);
                replay_text.setText(message);


                cancell.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        replylayout.removeAllViews();
                        startActivity(getIntent());

                    }
                });





            }
        });




            }

            return true;

        }

   });
```

I want to implement setOnItemLongClickListener on list view when long press on list item then perform other activity like delete and edit functionality. when press long click then give error cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Comment: Post your chatMessages class here.

Comment: Also note: you expect from people to spend their time to help you with your problem. So you should be willing to at least spend the time required to properly format/indent all of your code, instead of dumping such a mess on us that consists to 20% or so of useless empty lines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
String value = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

With This

```
String value = String.valueOf(listView.getItemAtPosition(position));
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in this line

```
String value = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

I definitely not sure that your listview is filled with String items as later in the code you call

```
chatMessages.get(position).getMessageID()
```

So your value should be something like

```
ChatMessage value = (ChatMessage) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

And in your adapter you need to change these methods (if they are not changed already):

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return items.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String value = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

View cant be cast into string. I think above code should be (presume the item content on your list view is text):

```
String value = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```